# Archiving Emails from Outlook Express in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, email, backup, archiving

I've used Outlook Express for years and I believed I used it in my last desktop which used Windows XP.   but, I've been using a Windows Vista laptop since about 2009 to which I somehow migrated all my email that I had on Windows XP.
But, I don't think I'm using Outlook Express but Windows Mail according to Help.

Now, I'd like to Archive the approximately 17 GB of email data I have.  Yes,  I think I managed to find the email files.   Does anyone know the PROPER way of copying this to my portable Archive F: Drive without corrupting the data?

I was going to just have the external drive copy each email but that will probably take forever.  There must be a better way to backup these files so I can transfer them to another laptop W8, or have a backup archive?

Any references?

Answer (score 0):

For Email Backup I use the Tool [MailStore Home](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home-email-archiving.aspx). It stores all emails a small database where you can later easily search for emails.